# Best practice for looping a function in C#

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to create a class in my program I'm writing that will send data to a USB port (Connected to an Arduino), and if the Arduino returns a certain string e.g. "HelloWorld", if will repeat the function.

I want this to just constantly loop in the background, what would be the best way to do this? Would it be using async and await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread would do just fine:

```
var t = new Thread(() => {
   while(true)
   {
     var msg = ApiGetMessage(); // Whatver this method is
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
});

t.Start();
```

Comment: There's no point in creating a thread and just joining it - if it's meant to be in the background, don't call `Join`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but the question is multithreaded in essence. Somewhere, there needs to be another thread that should keep the main loop running.

Comment: So in the ApiGetMessage() function is where I'd have all my logic for writing to USB, waiting for the response and processing it?

Comment: Okay, thanks :), I'll give that a try later on when I get in from work, but this looks like it will be exactly what I need.

Comment: I ended up not going down the loop a function route, but this did work great, apart from rather than using `t.Sleep` I had to use `Thread.Sleep`